# Can't remove punctuation in Solr

Tags: drupal, solr

I have a solr install to query content on a Drupal site. Many of the title fields have punctuation at the start of the string and so when I sort by title the punctuation appears top of the list.

I would like to get solr to ignore the the title when sorting by title but none of the solutions I have tried work.

I am fairly new to solr and so it may be something really simple that I am doing wrong... I don't really understand much of what is going on in the schema.xml file!

The title field is called label in solr and I have tried various methods in solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory which do not work.

```
<field name="label" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"     termVectors="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<copyField source="label" dest="sort_label"/>

<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
<charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
           pattern="(^\p{Punct}+)" replacement="" replace="all"
    />
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>

    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            protected="protwords.txt"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>

  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
…
</analyzer>
```

My query is 
                  start=0&rows=25&q=education&fl=id%2Centity_id%2Centity_type%2Cbundle%2Cbundle_name%2Csort_label%2Css_language%2Cis_comment_count%2Cds_created%2Cds_changed%2Cscore%2Cpath%2Curl%2Cis_uid%2Ctos_name%2Czm_parent_entity%2Css_filemime%2Css_file_entity_title%2Css_file_entity_url&pf=content%5E2.0&&sort=sort_label%20asc

Comment: can you share the fielType text from your schema.xml?

Comment: Done - sorry the opening fieldtype tag was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done with the `WordDelimiterFilterFactory`. Set `generateWordParts=1.` Add this filter to your

After modifying the `schema.xml` restart the server and re-index the data.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>

        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                protected="protwords.txt"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1"
                catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="0"
                preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>

      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: can you try the one I have added now...?Lets check if this works for you?

Comment: This seems to have caused some problems on the search, I don't think my settings for bias and other tweaks are working any more. Is it supposed to have the analyser type="index" removed? I think that is causing the problem

Comment: if you don't specify the type then it considered same for indexing(query) and for query...If you want a different analyzer for index then you need to mention the types...Here if you want to user same for index and query then no need to specify it. if You want separate analyzer for both stages then create seperate and mention....

Comment: BTW...did analyse the same in solr analysis tool...how it is parsing the text while indexing and while quering...Let me know what is not working...

Comment: I think it is working - however i have a lot of errors in my drupal log, and various modules are not working at all. i don't know if this is connected or a different problem...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108910/discussion-between-abhijit-bashetti-and-ankles).

Comment: Hi thanks for helping fix this! I have had to upgrade from Solr 4 to Solr 5 now, and the problem is occurring again... I have opened a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36798803/cant-ignore-punctuation-in-titles-solr-5-and-drupal - hope you can help!