# Can't ignore punctuation in titles - Solr 5 and Drupal

Tags: drupal, solr, solr5

The other week I posted a question about removing punctuation from solr search in Drupal. That was using Solr 4. However, since then the development I am doing has changed from solr 4 to solr 5, and now I am having the same problem but the fix at [Can't remove punctuation in Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543848/cant-remove-punctuation-in-solr) no longer works. This causes problems when sorting by titles since a lot of content titles have quotes around.

```
<field name="label" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            protected="protwords.txt"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I've tried adding the following rules but apostrophes and quotation marks stay there stubbornly and interfere when sorting by titles, putting anything with quotes at the beginning first on the list.

```
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.ApostropheFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
        pattern="^\p{Punct}*(.*?)\p{Punct}*$"
        replacement="$1"/>
```

Comment: Did you tried the same field type...? Or try by removing the char filter ...

Comment: I've just tried removing the char filter, no success with that. Can you explain what you mean about the same field type?

Answer (score 0):

All of the Solr solutions I tried were ineffective unfortunately, so I solved it from the Drupal side which turned out to be a lot simpler. The code below replaces all special characters and numbers, turns the string to lowercase and then adds it to the solr document. The second function adds it to the available sort methods.

```
function my_module_apachesolr_index_document_build(ApacheSolrDocument $document, $entity, $entity_type, $env_id) {

      # to keep letters only
      $title = trim($entity->title);
      $title = str_replace(' ', '_', $title);
      $title = preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i', '', $title);
      $title = strtolower($title);
      $document->addField('ss_new_sort',$title);

}

function my_module_apachesolr_query_prepare(DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query) {
      $query->setAvailableSort('ss_new_sort', array('title' => t('Title'), 'default' => 'asc'));
}
```